# Windows 10 Administrator rights needed when dev command prompt is run as administrator

Tags: windows, administrator, visual-studio-2017, code-signing

Maybe I work today too long but:

[image]

What are the additional (another) admin rights?
Windows is killing me.

Answer (score 1):

> What are the additional Administrator rights?

You need to give your user account access to the key container located at `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys`

> In case you reset your key container to a new one, and forget where it is.. you can reset the key container for the strong name utility using sn.exe -c. So, if the account access fix doesn't work, you may be using an alternate key store so a reset may be in order.

I would try `sn.exe -c` before if changing the permission on the folder does not work.

Source: [sn.exe fails with Access Denied error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887/sn-exe-fails-with-access-denied-error-message)